# jQuery BBQ Push State with '?x=y' Query

Tags: javascript, jquery-bbq

I have been using http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/ push and react to URL's (AJAX loaded URLS)...

Currently I have Urls like:

```
article/category/specific -> http://mypage.com/#article/category/specific
article/single/id -> http://mypage.com/#article/single/id
```

And so on, that works really well...

Now I have the need to augment that further with some parameters like ?l=http://mypage.com/whereicamefrom

This is for very specific situations where I wish that the user can store/bookmark the current url, but needs to know where that url started. Specifically when the URL changes by other means that the user clicking linkes etc...

Like performing a search, because searching would make the following url:

```
search/query -> http://mypage.com/#search/query

//I Would like (): 
search/query -> http://mypage.com/#search/query?l=article/category/specific
search/query -> http://mypage.com/#search/query?l=article/single/id
//(Depending on where you came from)
```

If I just try to pushstate with 'search/query?l=article/single/id' however, ? gets transformed to '%3F'...

**DOH!!!!!! Never mind... this didn't work due to another thing, i missed a "#" in the start of the hash I tried to push on page search... Ohh god... good thing that typing down your question can get your thoughts out of the circle your sitting in.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DOH!!!!!! Never mind... this didn't work due to another thing, i missed a "#" in the start of the hash I tried to push on page search... Ohh god... good thing that typing down your question can get your thoughts out of the circle your sitting in.**

So I pushed: 'search/query?l=article/single/id"
Where I should have pushed: '#search/query?l=article/single/id"

Then it works...
(I feel a bit stupid now)